# ¿Cómo se originó la expresión "tener mano izquierda"?

Tags: expresiones, historia

El DLE define *[mano izquierda](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OF9CzGo#BwyykVa)* desde 1992 como:

> Habilidad o astucia para manejarse o resolver situaciones difíciles.

Aunque la primera aparición fue en el *Academia Manual* de 1984 como "habilidad o astucia para manejarse".

Estaba pensando cómo se originaría la expresión, y empecé a inventarme posibles teorías, como que tenía que ver con aquello de la mano del demonio, que consigue lo que quiere usando argucias y tal; o a lo mejor en la época medieval, en contraposición a conseguir algo con la mano derecha (la de la espada, es decir, por la fuerza).

Sin embargo, en el foro de hispanistas del Instituto Cervantes [leo lo siguiente](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=43767):

> Dije que en el mundo del toro [la expresión "tener mano izquierda"] significó —y significa— simplemente 'saber torear al natural', esto es, de modo regular, pues torear con la mano derecha es arte menor.

Es decir, que la expresión provendría del mundo del toro:

> [...] hoy, en cualquier tertulia taurina se oye que para triunfar en el arte de Cúchares se puede ser de derechas, pero hay que «tener mano izquierda», porque la izquierda —la de citar de frente, la de citar con valor— es la que trae la fama y los dineros.

La verdad es que no me imaginaba este origen. En todo caso, ¿es este realmente el origen de la expresión? Parece plausible pero no cita fuentes. ¿Cuáles son los primeros textos escritos que la usan?

Answer (score 2):

La entrada en el foro del CVC sobre la expresión [«mano izquierda»](http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=43767) dice que esa expresión viene del mundo del toro, donde:

> «Tener mano izquierda» sigue siendo 'saber torear al natural'; en el lenguaje coloquial, asombrosamente, vale por 'tener astucia o habilidad para manejarse'.

No es una explicación etimológica, pero sí es una explicación conocida. Yo la he escuchado más de una vez.

Por otro lado recomiendo echar un vistazo al artículo de María del Mar Forment y Triantafylliá Efthymiou, de la Universidad de Barcelona, [*Las nociones de derecha e izquierda y las creencias a ellas asociadas en español y en griego*](http://www.anmal.uma.es/Numero9/Forment.htm), un artículo interesante, de más de 9000 palabras.

Con relación a la mano izquierda, en los pocos sentidos positivos que tiene, apunta:

> **Mano izquierda**. Con sentido figurado el DRAE define así este sintagma: «Habilidad o astucia para manejarse o resolver situaciones difíciles».
>
> ***Tener mano izquierda***, «Poseer habilidad o astucia para resolver situaciones difíciles».
> Tanto en este caso como en el del sintagma nominal *mano izquierda*, las locuciones presentadas, a pesar de contener el vocablo *izquierda*, poseen un sentido positivo. *Tener mano izquierda* significa, en cierto modo, ser capaz de realizar con la mano izquierda acciones tan útiles como las que se llevan a cabo con la derecha y, en consecuencia, dominar los impulsos negativos e irracionales que siempre se han relacionado con la siniestra. Así, la persona que tiene mano izquierda, en sentido figurado, es una persona hábil, no tanto desde un punto de vista manual o físico, como para desenvolverse con facilidad en la resolución de problemas.

Comment: En el texto de la pregunta ya hago mención al enlace que comentas en tu respuesta. Precisamente la pregunta es si ese texto tiene fundamento.

Comment: Cierto, según vi tu respuesta recordé la entrada en el CVC, la busqué y los puse como respuesta. No citan ninguna referencia, salvo el libro de La Tauromaquia  de Pepe-Hillo, pero los que participan se suelen documentar. No se que se hace en estos casos ¿borro la respuesta?

Comment: Algunos la borran y la editan para mejorarla, siempre puedes rescatar la respuesta más adelante cuando creas que ya está lista.

Answer (score 2):

Sinceramente creía que esta expresión viene del mundo ecuestre. Tradicionalmente se toman las riendas con la mano izquierda ya que es bastante más sensible que la derecha. Las riendas están unidas al bocado en la boca del caballo. Para decir que hay ser sensible con las riendas, se dice "tener mano izquierda ".

Answer (score 2):

Tener mano izquierda viene originalmente de los espadachines y duelistas.
Espada en la mano derecha, y la daga más corta, también llamada “mano izquierda” en la mano opuesta,
La daga se usaba para parar ciertos golpes del contrario que no eran fáciles de parar con la espada que era más larga.
Tener buena mano izquierda era y es todavía sinónimo de saber salir de situaciones difíciles.
Aunque a mi que me encantan los toros, me apuntaría a los pases por naturales