# ¿Cómo ganó "zurdo" el significado de "homosexual" en cierto países hispanoamericanos?

Tags: etimología, significado, nicaragua, república-dominicana, panamá

El otro día estaba hablando con un amigo argentino de política y dijo que él era "más bien *zurdo*", cosa que en el contexto de la conversación se entendió perfectamente.

Después, me vino la duda sobre si [diestro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=DiPpTTa) tendría connotaciones paralelas al hablar de política (que parece ser que nos las tiene), por lo que quise comparar ambas entradas en el DRAE y en el diccionario de americanismos. Consultando este último por supuesto esperaba ver la entrada que dice que un [zurdo](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=zurdo) es una "Persona que tiene ideas de izquierda" (en Gu, Ni, RD, Bo, Ch, Py, Ar; Ur), pero no me esperaba la segunda, que dice que

> (en Ni, Pa, RD). Referido a un hombre, *homosexual*.

¿Cómo ganó "zurdo" el significado de "homosexual" en cierto países hispanoamericanos? ¿Cuál es la relación/evolución entre ambos términos?

Comment: Muy curioso. Lo único que se me ocurre es que, por el reglamento de circulación, lo correcto es caminar por la acera de la derecha. ¿Tendrá que ver con la acera de en frente?"

Comment: @FGSUZ Interesante idea. Dado que lo más común (porcentaje de la población) es ser diestro (los zurdos son aprox. del 8 al 13% de la población mundial, de acuerdo a wikipedia), el "ser zurdo" puede ser una analogía para referirse a un colectivo que no sigue "la norma" en algún sentido.

Answer (score 3):

Left handedness has long been stigmatised in many societies, coming to be superstitiously associated with various negative characteristics. This is analogous to stigmatisation of other relatively uncommon phenomena in people which contrast how the 'normal' majority act or look e.g. albinism, dwarfism:

> Many languages still contain references to left-handedness to convey awkwardness, dishonesty, stupidity, or other undesirable qualities. Even in relatively advanced societies, left-handed people were historically (and in some cases still are) forced as children to use their right hands for tasks which they would naturally perform with the left, such as eating or writing.

This prejudice has bled into a number of expressions in many languages, including Spanish:

> - Cuando alguien hace algo fuera de la ley o de la moral, suele hacerlo… *por la izquierda*

- Si tienes un mal día es porque te has levantado… *con el pie izquierdo o por el lado izquierdo de la cama.*
- Una persona que no sirve para nada… *es un cero a la izquierda.*
- Al que no sabe bailar le dicen que tiene… *dos pies izquierdos.*
- Las aves que anuncian malos agüeros decimos que vienen… *por la izquierda.*

The word [*siniestro*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23081/cu%C3%A1ndo-se-estableci%C3%B3-izquierda-como-sustituto-de-siniestra-en-el-espa%C3%B1ol) itself has been displaced by *izquierda, zurdo* due to the taboo nature of the word.

Due to these negative historical associations, lefthandedness itself has come to be used in many expressions as a euphemism for other perceived negative characteristics which differ from 'the norm'. One example is, as you note, being gay:

> In 19th-century Europe, homosexuals were referred to as "left-handed".

This connotation is visible today in the English phrase "batting lefty", as well as the South American Spanish use of *zurdo*.

---

- [https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zurdera#Consideraciones_culturales_y_discriminación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zurdera#Consideraciones_culturales_y_discriminaci%C3%B3n)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_against_left-handed_people#Expressions_and_colloquialisms
- https://www.primerahora.com/puerto-rico/blog/prof-gabriel-paizy/posts/expresionesprejuiciadas-1294008/

Comment: Cabe señalar que también tenemos la expresión "[tener mano izquierda](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23998/5481)", que es "Habilidad o astucia para manejarse o resolver situaciones difíciles."

Comment: Statistics have been collected that show a correlation between left-handedness (or being ambidextrous) and homosexuality (for both men and women) (which I do not understand).

Comment: It's worth noting that the English word sinister comes from the same Latin word as siniestro.  Also, the word siniestro is sometimes used as a noun, meaning an event that causes damage. like a car crash.  People have seen something "wrong" about the left side ever since Roman times.  And the fact that most people are right handed is enough for some  people to view the minority as somehow sinister.

Comment: As far as the use of left and right in politics, this comes from the seating arrangement in the French legislature during the First Republic.